# Insert on conflict update

Tags: postgresql

I have two similar tables with different values:

**users_groups_old**

```
user_id | group_id | rating | registered
----------------------------------------
1       | 1        | 1      |
1       | 2        | 2      |
2       | 2        | 3      |
```

**users_groups**

```
user_id | group_id | rating | registered
----------------------------------------
1       | 1        | 10     |
1       | 2        | 20     |
```

I want to "merge" two tables or sum the rating if the row already exists.
Finally I want to get the following table (table key is: user_id + group_id):

**users_groups**

```
user_id | group_id | rating | registered
----------------------------------------
1       | 1        | 11     |
1       | 2        | 22     |
2       | 2        | 3      |
```

**I trying the following**

```
insert into users_groups
select *
from users_groups_old
on conflict (user_id, group_id)
do update
  set rating = users_groups.rating + excluded.rating;
```

But got the error

```
SQL Error [42P10]: ERROR: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification
```

Which I can't understand, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: In `psql`, issue the command `\d users_groups`.  Verify that you have a `PRIMARY KEY` made up of `(user_id, group_id)`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the database cannot identify the unique constraint for `(user_id, group_id)`. Please check if it is defined correctly and try using the constraint name directly:

```
...
on conflict on constraint <constraint name>
...
```